# How can I find the index of an object inside a Array using underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, javascript-framework

I want to get the index of the given value inside a Array using underscore.js.

Here is my case

```
var array = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'},
             {'id': 2, 'name': 'yyy'},
             {'id': 3, 'name': 'zzz'}];

var searchValue = {'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'};
```

I used the following code,

```
var index = _.indexOf(array, function(data) { 
                alert(data.toSource()); //For testing purpose 
                return data === searchValue; 
            });
```

Also tried this too

```
var index = _.indexOf(array, {id: searchValue.id});
```

But it `returns -1` . Since it does not enter into that function. So I didn't get that alert message.

Whats wrong with my code.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var array = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'},
             {'id': 2, 'name': 'yyy'},
             {'id': 3, 'name': 'zzz'}];

var searchValue = {'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'},
    index = -1;

_.each(array, function(data, idx) { 
   if (_.isEqual(data, searchValue)) {
      index = idx;
      return;
   }
});

console.log(index); //0
```

In your snippet `data === searchValue` compares the objects' references, you don't want to do this. On the other hand, if you use `data == searchValue` you are going to compare objects' string representations i.e. `[Object object]` if you don't have redefined `toString` methods.

So the correct way to compare the objects is to use `_.isEqual`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yep, agree. Fixed my answer.

Comment: You might want to review how [`isEqual`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) is used. :-)

Answer (score 16):

I'd strongly suggest taking a look at lodash. It contains quite a bit of nifty little functions that unfortunately underscore is lacking.

For example, this is what you would do with lodash:

```
var array = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'yyy'},
           {'id': 3, 'name': 'zzz'}];

var searchValue = {'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'};


var index = _.findIndex(array, searchValue); 
console.log(index === 0); //-> true
```

http://lodash.com/docs#findIndex

Also, if you're bound to using Underscore - you can grab lodash's underscore build at https://raw.github.com/lodash/lodash/2.4.1/dist/lodash.underscore.js

---

#### ES2015

With ES2015 now in wide use (through transpilers like Babel), you could forego lodash and underscore for the task at hand and use native methods:

```
var arr = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}];

arr.findIndex(i => i.id === 1); // 0
```

Answer (score 3):

May be my suggestion will give you advice.

Why do you use callback for indexof method? The signature of indexof in underscore.js is the following:

```
_.indexOf(array, value, [isSorted])
```

find could be better for this task:

```
_.find(array, function(item, index) {
  if (item.id == searchValue.id) {
    alert(index);
  }
});
```

Comment: Interesting. The documentation of Underscore is lacking there, as they don't explain what are the arguments of the predicates (they only show examples with the value).

Answer (score 2):

With objects, `===` and `==` check to see if two references refer to the **same** object; it doesn't check for *equivalent* objects:

```
var a = {foo: "bar"};
var b = {foo: "bar"};
console.log(a === b); // false, `a` and `b` refer to different (but equivalent) objects
a = b = {something: "here"};
console.log(a === b); // true, `a` and `b` refer to the *same* object
```

You have to test the object's properties to make the decision. In your case, the `id` property looks like a good option, or if you want to compare all of the properties, you might use Underscore's [`isEqual`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual).

Answer (score 2):

Underscore uses native indexOf method if available,else applies fallback. Thus, for a list of objects you have to implement it in some other way.

One example could be

```
_.chain(array).pluck("key").indexOf("value").value();
```

or

```
_.map(array,function(e) { return e.key; }).indexOf(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have complicated objects, and want to search one object in the collection looking for a certain property, just go with:

```
 _.indexOf(arrayObj, _.findWhere(arrayObj, {id: 1})  );
```

Where "arrayObj" is the collection with objects, "id" is the prop, and "1" is the value being in search.

Answer (score 1):

i am using find index

```
 _.findIndex(array, searchValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.find(array, function(item, index) {
  if (item.id == searchValue.id) {
    alert(index);
  }
});
```