# How to get remove a particular json object from an array of json objects , in node.js

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I have an array of json objects, for eg

```
 var user =[ { id: 1, name: 'linto', img: 'img' },
  { id: 2, name: 'shinto', img: 'img' },
  { id: 3, name: 'hany', img: 'img' } ]
```

From this, i need to remove  a particular json object

`{ id: 2, name: 'shinto', img: 'img' }.`

ie the output array should be  like this

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'linto', img: 'img' },
  { id: 3, name: 'hany', img: 'img' } ]
```

Is there any function in node.js to  achieve this ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

use delete command for that.

E.g.

```
delete user[index]
```

EDIT: `splice` command works better in case of array as it fully removes the element. In case of delete null replaces the deleted element.

```
user.splice(0,<index>);
```

Full code :

```
var user =[ { id: 1, name: 'linto', img: 'img' },
  { id: 2, name: 'shinto', img: 'img' },
  { id: 3, name: 'hany', img: 'img' } ]

  alert(JSON.stringify(user));

  user.splice(0,1);

  alert(JSON.stringify(user));
```

Comment: index on what basis ?

Comment: i know, if we loop , it will ok.B ut is there any  predefined function for that ?

Comment: I think in underscore.js some function is there to find index , this post might help you for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522319/how-can-i-find-the-index-of-an-object-inside-a-array-using-underscore-js

Comment: @Sachin.That whats i exactly want.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an underscore way for the same.

**[reject](http://underscorejs.org/#reject)**

```js
var user = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'linto',
  img: 'img'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'shinto',
  img: 'img'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'hany',
  img: 'img'
}]
console.log(_.reject(user, function(usr) {
  return usr.name == 'shinto';
}));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
```